# Finding controls on page load event for a page which is inherited from Master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am unable to find controls on page load event for a page which is inherited from Master page.
Here is my code-

```
Image img =FindControl("ourPimg0") as Image;
```

Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to find control inside the master page you should 
**this.Master.FindControl("controlName")**.

Other case is with you are inside master page and want to find a control inside a page so you should **ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("controlName")**.

Please also check:

- [How to access content page controls from master page in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979669/how-to-access-content-page-controls-from-master-page-in-asp-net)
- [Nested Masterpages and .FindControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578188/nested-masterpages-and-findcontrol)

Answer (score 0):

while checking for controls in child page use the below code

ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("controlName") .It lists out the control for that particular field.